# Having trouble when implementing CNN+LSTM model that i made into a video

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to test my model on video for prediction.

I want to make prediction using my `cnn(alexnet)+lstm` model on a video that I have, but when it runs, nothing from the video appear.

Here is my **code**:

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture("Data Fix/Data16_133.mp4")

while(vid.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    vid.set(3, 480)
    vid.set(4, 240)
    start = time.time()
    if ret == True:
        total_frame += 1
        draw = frame.copy()
        draw = cv2.cvtColor(draw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        scale_percent = 20 # percent of original size
        width = 224
        height = width
        dim = (width, height)
        frame_set = cv2.resize(draw, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        frame_set=np.arange(10*width*height*3).reshape(10,width, height, 3)
        frame_set.reshape(10, width, height, 3).shape
        frame_set = np.expand_dims(frame_set, axis=0)
        result=model.predict_on_batch(frame_set)

        cv2.imshow('Result', result)
        print(result)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break            

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

when I print the result, it keep printing this value over and over without showing nothing from the `cv2.imshow`

```
[[0.0602112  0.01403825 0.3782384  0.5362205  0.01129159]]
```

does anyone have a clue about this?
any answer would be grateful

currently I'm trying [this tutorial](https://github.com/ljw20155136/Lip-reading-by-CNN-and-LSTM-architecture/blob/master/Lip%20Reading%20Tutorial%20Training.ipynb) to make the model and how I put the dataset too are same, the different are I didn't use the `MobileNet` transfer learning, I modified it using `AlexNet` model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your results are not an image that you can display using `OpenCV`. Your results are output from your model which according to the shared notebook is a classification model and represents the class probabilities. I assume you are trying to predict some class corresponding to the video. If you want to see the frame then you have to use it like this:

```
cv2.imshow('frame', frame) # to see the frame
# below to see the draw
cv2.imshow('draw', draw)
```

Edit: If you want to show the predicted class on the image then
do the following

```
# Get the predicted class from the result using argmax
pred_class = np.argmax(result)
# Here I assume that the index is the desired class like most cases

# Now we will write the class label on the image
# Set the font and place
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
org = (50, 50)
cv2.putText(frame, str(pred_class), org, font, .5, (255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

# now just show the frame
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
```

Comment: but if i show the frame and draw only isnt it wont show the predict on the video too?

Comment: @JuniorPython you have to be clear about what you want? do you want to show the result class on the frame?

Comment: i mean its clearly in the post that i want to show the result of the prediction using my model, not just show the video.....

Comment: It does work and it shows the prediction, sadly i try to other video the prediction didnt change and always has the same class, i think its from my model

Thank you for your help